# Can't run npm install in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, npm

I don't really know what's the cause of npm not working on my wsl. My project is located at `/home/username/BISECT../...` but it seems that this gives me a hint `EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\oliver\BISECTHOSTING\website\node_modules\@vue\compiler-core'`

```
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated vue@2.7.16: Vue 2 has reached EOL and is no longer actively maintained. See https://v2.vuejs.org/eol/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated vue@2.7.16: Vue 2 has reached EOL and is no longer actively maintained. See https://v2.vuejs.org/eol/ for more details.
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     '\\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu\\home\\oliver\\BISECTHOSTING\\website\\node_modules\\@vue',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\oliver\BISECTHOSTING\website\node_modules\@vue\compiler-core'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: '\\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu\\home\\oliver\\BISECTHOSTING\\website\\node_modules\\@vue\\compiler-core'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\oliver\BISECTHOSTING\website\node_modules\@vuelidate\core\node_modules\vue-demi
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./scripts/postinstall.js
```

Comment: npm commands works flawlessly on my windows os

Comment: This doesn't look like WSL. The paths are separated by \ not /. Anyway, the permissions are messed up so you could start by deleting "node_modules" before reinstalling it. To actually run the commands inside WSL Ubuntu and not the Windows outside, you need to run `wsl` or some other command

Comment: I just ran the wsl on windows terminal however I don't think that makes any diff. I am starting to think this is about memory issue. When I check the node_modules I can see 1-2 packages installed. I keep repeating the delete node_modules dir then run npm but still the same outcome

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am also facing the same scenario with the same kind of error when i try to install npm modules via WSL. If you the solution, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I had not used the specific version of node. I have installed the node via nvm but have not specified the node version I must use.

So when I type `node -v` it is undefined or something like that